# Calculating with python and appending result to file or register

Tags: command-line, register, vimscript-python

I found [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1235) which allows you to evaluate a Python expression and displays the result in the command line. You just have to add

```
:command! -nargs=+ Calc :py print <args>
:py from math import *
```

to your `.vimrc` and then you can do e.g.

```
:Calc sum([x^2 for x in range(100)])
```

Which displays `4950`in my command line, as if I had executed `:echo 4950`.
This is convenient, but I would like to know how I can either append the result at the location of my cursor, or add it to a certain register.

Comment: `py vim.current.buffer.append(str(sum([x^2 for x in range(100)])), vim.current.window.cursor[0])`

Comment: @AlexKroll This gives me an error:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1 in <module>
    NameError: name 'vim' is not defined`

Comment: 'py import vim' of course!

Comment: @AlexKroll I was completely unaware that Python had a vim module (or does it?) I prefer your solution to philolo1's but if someone could point me to a command to append the result to a register, that would be great.
If you make this an answer I'll probably accept it.

Comment: If your Vim compiled with `+python` or `+puthon3` internal Python interpreteur have module `vim`,

`:he python-vim` for more exploration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function! CalcAndAppend(expr)
py << EOF
import vim
evaluated = eval(vim.eval("a:expr"))

vim.current.buffer.append(str(evaluated), vim.current.window.cursor[0])
EOF
endfunction

function! CalcAndAppendRegister(reg, expr)
py << EOF
import vim
evaluated = eval(vim.eval("a:expr"))
evalString = "'" + str(evaluated) + "'"
register = vim.eval("a:reg")

vim.command("let @%s=%s" % (register,evalString))
EOF
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ Calc call CalcAndAppend(<q-args>) 

command! -register -nargs=+ CalcReg call CalcAndAppendRegister("<reg>",<q-args>)
```

Usage:
`:Calc 2+2`
appends `4` to the current buffer on one line below after cursor
`:CalcReg a sum[x^2 for x in range(100)]` put `4950` to the register named `a`

Comment: It looks to me like this uses vim to evaluate the expression and not python.

Comment: You're right! Look edited answer!

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. I added support for floating point numbers to avoid `E806: using Float as a String`.

Answer (score 5):

That's what `pyeval()` is good for.  The only (minor) inconvenience is that you have to quote the expression you want to evaluate:

```
let @a = pyeval('sum([x^2 for x in range(100)])')
```

It works for all data types, and you can do with it everything you can do with a Vim expression.  For example:

```
echo pyeval('[x^2 for x in range(100)]')
```

Answer (score 3):

I do the following:

I create somewhere a calculator.py file containing this.

```
 import sys                                                                  
 print eval(sys.argv[1])
```

Then in vim i can do the command:

```
read! python calculator.py "[x^2 for x in range(100)]"
```

Comment: I'm curious: why use `eval` instead of `python -c`?

Comment: No reason, i did not know the command, so you can also so do 
python -c "[x^2 for x in range(100)]".

Comment: `python -c 'print [x^2 for x in range(100)]'`, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the great `vim`.
2. Enter insert mode and add a python3 statement inside your text file buffer:

   print(5*5)
3. Go to normal mode (ESC or CTRL+C)
4. Press `!!` making sure the cursor is above that line. Your command bar will be filled like:

   :.!
5. fill the rest of command with `python`

   :.!python
6. press enter end you line will be evaluated:

   25

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question of putting the answer in a register, or inserting it at the cursor.